# gson parse always null with lists inside lists

Tags: android, json, gson

I've got some arrays down the line, but somehow they don't get parsed correctly...

First time i'm using gson so no idea... (reading all clues online, lead me to believe i've got the structure right...

The information inside the ResponseResult.ResponseCode are all correctly matched. But the ResponseData isn't.

I did the init with:

```
ResponseResult responseResult = gson.fromJson(new String(response),ResponseResult.class);
```

my classes:

```
public class ResponseResult
{
    public ResponseCode responseCode;
    public ResponseData responseData;
}

public class ResponseCode
{
    public int errorCode;
    public String errorMessage;
}

public class ResponseData
{
    // support
    public int support_id;

    // faq
    public List<ResponseFaqSection> faq;

}

public class ResponseFaqSection
{
    public int section_id;
    public String section_language;
    public int section_order;
    public String section_title;
    public String section_subtitle;
    public String section_image;
    public  String section_created;
    public  String section_updated;
    public int section_published;
    public int section_deleted;
    public List<ResponseFaqItem> items;
}

public class ResponseFaqItem
{
    public int faq_id;
    public String faq_language;
    public int section_id;
    public int faq_order;
    public String faq_title;
    public String faq_subtitle;
    public String faq_message;
    public String faq_image;
    public String faq_created;
    public String faq_updated;
    public  int faq_published;
    public int faq_deleted;
}
```

And the json"

```
{
"responseCode":{
"errorCode":0,
"errorMessage":"api_error_ok"
},
"responseData":{
"faq":[
{
"section_id":"3",
"section_language":"english",
"section_order":"0",
"section_title":"General",
"section_subtitle":"General Information",
"section_image":"",
"section_created":"2017-04-27 13:55:48",
"section_updated":"2017-04-27 13:55:48",
"section_published":"1",
"section_deleted":"0",
"items":[
{
"faq_id":"1",
"section_id":"3",
"faq_language":"english",
"faq_order":"0",
"faq_title":"Can I contact Jiffy?",
"faq_subtitle":"Can I contact Jiffy?",
"faq_message":"Yes, you can contact jiffy through the contact form inside the application.",
"faq_image":"",
"faq_created":"2017-04-27 13:57:34",
"faq_updated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
"faq_published":"1",
"faq_deleted":"0"
}
]
},
{
"section_id":"4",
"section_language":"english",
"section_order":"1",
"section_title":"Security",
"section_subtitle":"Questions about security",
"section_image":"",
"section_created":"2017-04-27 13:55:48",
"section_updated":"2017-04-27 13:55:48",
"section_published":"1",
"section_deleted":"0",
"items":[
{
"faq_id":"2",
"section_id":"4",
"faq_language":"english",
"faq_order":"0",
"faq_title":"Is my line secure?",
"faq_subtitle":"Is my line secure?",
"faq_message":"Yes, Jiffy uses a 256-bit SSL Certificate to secure your connection.",
"faq_image":"",
"faq_created":"2017-04-27 13:57:34",
"faq_updated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
"faq_published":"1",
"faq_deleted":"0"
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

After playing with the code the problems is with the "sub list" called "items"

```
public class ResponseFaqSection
    {
        public int section_id;
        public String section_language;
        public int section_order;
        public String section_title;
        public String section_subtitle;
        public String section_image;
        public  String section_created;
        public  String section_updated;
        public int section_published;
        public int section_deleted;
        public List<ResponseFaqItem> items; <--- FAILS HERE
    }
```

Comment: In `ResponseData` what part is wrong? Can you share your code that is used to serialize?

Comment: It came from a REST service, so wan't serialized in android.   ResponseResult responseResult = gson.fromJson(new String(response),ResponseResult.class);

Comment: the problem is responseResult.responseData.faq is always null...

Comment: as it seems... i have been really stupid.... pointing my rest service to the wrong entry point.....

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem line (in Faqsection):

```
 List<faq> items[];
```

You are telling it the input is a list of arrays. It can't be both.

Comment: Weird. What did you change it to?

Comment: As a side note: Why do you have a class with a small letter at the start of the name? Always start classes with a capital letter.

Comment: I was just trying to test and make it work... i've now all changed the objects into split class files. with Capital letters. I removed the [] from the item... still null

Comment: Best to update the question with the new structure so we can see exactly what is there.